# Multivariate-Multi-objective Optimization Problem: $x+y+z = 1$ and $x^2+y^2+z^2 = 1$

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization

$x, y, z $ are three distinct positive real numbers such that

$$\begin{cases}&x + y + z = 1\\
&{x^2} + {y^2} + {z^2} = 1\\
&x \ne y \ne z\\
&0 < x,y,z < 1
 \end{cases}$$

Is there any solution for $x, y, z $ ? If yes, how we can find the solution. Thank you.

Comment: What do you want to optimize ?

Comment: minimum possible values of $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$ subject to above constraints.

Comment: Note that $x \neq y \neq z $ does not mean they are **all** distinct. You must also add $x \neq z $. Unless $x $ and $z $ can be the same.

Comment: Merci, you're right. @RSerrao

Comment: @sci9 what do you mean by "minimum possible values of $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$"? That's a contradiction, you just fixed the value, there's nothing to minimize.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\begin{cases}x + y + z = 1\\0\leq x,y,z \leq 1\end {cases}$$ is the equation for a tetrahedron whose vertices are located in the three axis. The vertices are at $x = 1, y = 1, z = 1$.

$$x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1$$ is the equation for a sphere with radius 1.

The sphere and that tetrahedron only intersect in the tetrahedron's vertices. i.e. on $(1,0,0), (0,1,0)$ and $(0,0,1) $.

Since you have restricted that the coordinates are all positive $> 0$, and strictly less than 1, there is no solution for your system.

Comment: Merci beaucoup.

Answer (score 2):

Since $0<x,y,z<1$, you have that $x^2<x, y^2<y$ and $z^2<z$. Plugging in the first two equations you get $$1=x^2+y^2+z^2<x+y+z=1$$ which is a contradiction.

Comment: Very simple answer, nice

Comment: @RSerrao Thank you. I like the geometric interpretations, because they are useful in more complex problems, so I did upvote you answer as well!

Comment: @RSerrao and JimmyR.: If we relieve the constraints such that $x,y,z$ can also get values between $(-1,0)$, it seems that the system has a solution. 
 Now, the question is how we can find this solution? $x,y,z \in ( - 1,0) \cup (0,1)$

Comment: Ok, this is a different question, so preferably do not ask it as a comment

Comment: Ok, I open a new question. Thank you.