# New Question: Find $x,y,z$ s.t. $x+y+z=1$ and $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$, and $x,y,z \in ( - 1,0) \cup (0,1)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, optimization

If in my earlier question [1], we relieve the constraints such that $x,y,z$ can also get values between $(−1,0)$, it seems that the system has a solution. Now, the question is how we can find this solution?

$$\begin{cases}&x + y + z = 1\\
&{x^2} + {y^2} + {z^2} = 1\\
&x \ne y \ne z, x \ne z\\
&x,y,z \in ( - 1,0) \cup (0,1)
 \end{cases}$$

--

[1] [Multivariate-Multi-objective Optimization Problem: $x+y+z = 1$ and $x^2+y^2+z^2 = 1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2035446/multivariate-multi-objective-optimization-problem-xyz-1-and-x2y2z2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First observe that exactly one of the $x,y,z$ must be in $(-1,0)$. Without loss assume that $x\in(-1,0)$ and $y,z \in (0,1)$. Then, the first condition gives 
\begin{align}y+z=1-x\implies& y^2+2yz+z^2=1-2x+x^2\\[0.2cm]\overset{(2)}\implies &1-x^2+2yz=1-2x+x^2\\[0.2cm]\implies& y=\frac{x(x-1)}z\end{align} Now, return and plug in the value of $y$ in $(1)$
\begin{align}x+\frac{x(x-1)}{z}+z=1\implies &z^2+z(x-1)+x(x-1)=0\\[0.2cm]\implies &\frac1{(x-1)}z^2+z+x=0\\[0.2cm]\implies& z_{1,2}=\left(-1\pm\sqrt{1-\frac{4x}{(x-1)}}\right)\cdot\frac{x-1}2\end{align} Now, the condition $z>0$ implies that we can drop the one solution (which is obviously negative) and hence obtain $$z=\left(-1+\sqrt{\frac{1+3x}{1-x}}\right)\cdot\frac{x-1}2$$ Since the term in the square root must me non-negative we get the restriction \begin{align}\frac{1+3x}{1-x}\ge0 \iff (1+3x)(1-x)\ge 0 \iff -\frac13\le x\le 1\end{align} which together with $x<0$ implies that $-\frac13\le x<0$. For these values of $x$ the given $z$ exists and is $>0$. With this value of $z$, $y$ becomes $$y=\frac{x(x-1)}{z}=\frac{2x}{-1+\sqrt{\frac{1+3x}{1-x}}}$$ Hence, it remains to find all $x$ such that $$x+\frac{2x}{-1+\sqrt{\frac{1+3x}{1-x}}}+\left(-1+\sqrt{\frac{1+3x}{1-x}}\right)\cdot\frac{x-1}{2}=1$$

Comment: You have $x+y+z=1$ which determines $z$ for a given $x$ (since you get a quadratic equation, there are (usually) two possible values). Geometrically, this is intersection of a sphere and a plane (which gives a circle) with additional weak conditions.

Comment: @Abstraction Thanks for your comment. So, you mean that I am missing some solutions? I think since it must be that $x<0$ and $y,z>0$ (up to renaming) then there is a unique solution for every value of $x$. Is this what you are saying?

Comment: @JimmyR. Thank you. Yes, I agree that one of the values must be between $(-1,0)$. However, according to the general solution you provided, if we choose the values as $x = -.25, z = .5$, and then $y = 0.625$, neither the first nor the second equation is satisfied!

Comment: @JimmyR. I say that you state $(-{1 \over 2}, {6 \over 7},{7 \over 8})$ is a solution while it clearly isn't. Intuitively you have two constraints for three-dimensional space, so two-dimensional solution is suspicious.

Comment: @Abstraction Ok, yes, I see that there is a problem somewhere. I will try to fix it. Thanks

Comment: Merci beaucoup. Beautiful solution!

Comment: @sci9 Thank you, but I find again that there is no solution. This seems ok to me, but what if I have a mistake in the calculations? Sorry, for the upset my friend.

Comment: $x+\frac{2x}{gx-1}+(gx-1)*x-1/2=1 
⇔\frac{4x}{gx-1}+(x-1)(gx+1)=0
⇔4x=(1-x)*(\frac{1+3x}{1-x}-1)
⇔4x=4x$ ・・・

Comment: @JimmyR. I think there is no mistake. BTW, the relations you found, determine the correct values that satisfy both equations. `x = -.25
, z = (-1 + sqrt((1+3*x)/(1-x))) * ((x-1)/2)
, y = x*(x-1)/z
, x+y+z == 1
, x^2+y^2+z^2 == 1` . However, the simplification of your last equation, made me a little suspicious! ;-)

Answer (score 2):

The set of solutions become a circle which intersect of next two spheres. 
$$(x-1/3)^2+(y-1/3)^2+(z-1/3)^2=2/3$$
$$x^2+y^2+z^2=1$$ except $x=y,y=z,z=x$.

Comment: Thank you for answer. Could you please clarify the way in which your first equation is obtained?

Comment: The foot of perpendicular to the plane is (1/3,1/3,1/3), and circumcenter's radius in the regular triangle of root2 is 2/3.

Comment: Excellent view! Thank you very much.